# Two dimensional recursive function in $O(\log n)$ time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

It is well known that a recursive sequence or $1$-d sequence can be calculated in $O( \log n)$ time given that it has the form

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} C_ka_{n-k},$$

where $C_k$ is a constant. Examples would include polynomials like $n^2$ or $n^3$, exponentials like $2^n$, and Fibonacci Numbers defined by $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}, a_0=0, a_1=1$. Factorials would not be included for example, because they are defined by $a_n=na_{n-1}$, and $C_k=n$ is not constant.

Let $a_{n,k}$ be a two dimensional sequence defined by

$$a_{n,k} = \sum_{i=0,j=0, (i\ne n \text{ }∧\text{ }j\ne k)}^{n,k}C_{i,j}a_{i,j}$$

where $C_{i,j}$ is constant.

Is it possible to compute $a_{n,k}$ in logarithmic time (a.k.a $O (\log n)$) or better?

I know one case where this is possible, namely if $a_{n,k}$ are coefficients of polynomials in a sequence ($1$-d recursive sequence), such that the degrees of each term differ by $1$. In this case, the diagonals of the sequence $a_{n,n+t}$ for some constant $t$, are $1$-d constant recursive functions, whose terms can be computed in $O(\log n)$ time. This doesn't use the initial relation in terms of two indices though as expected.

However, in certain cases, the diagonals do not form $1$-d constant recursive functions, namely when the degree difference of consecutive polynomial terms is more than $1$.

Comment: *Every* sequence has the form $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n C_k a_{n-k}$ for some constant $C_k$. What we really want is that $C_k = 0$ for all $k$ larger than some constant $K$.

Comment: The running time of $O(\log n)$ ignores the cost of arithmetic operations, which can be significant if the sequence grows exponentially.

Comment: Are you meaning for estimation something like $O(f(n,k))$ or you are searching conditions for exactly $O(\log n)$?

Comment: One standard way to analyze a 1D linear recurrence relation is with generating functions.  Have you tried doing the same for your 2D recurrence relation, i.e., letting $f(x,y)=\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} x^i y^j$ be the generating function for the sequence, finding a formula for the generating function, and then using that to expand it?   Does that lead anywhere useful?